# Netty - Opening too many tcp connections when i start the Netty server

Tags: netty

I am using netty 4.0.19 version to move the files from client to server. In my dev environment when i start the netty server it is opening only  one TCP connection and working as expected but when it is running on production server it is opening 58 tcp connections immediately after starting netty server and after client communication its count is keep on increasing.

Production server configuration:
cores: 12
CPUs : 48
Linux : Redhat enterprise edition

Dev server configuration:
cores : 2
CPUs : 4
Linux : cenOS